# Spring boot , pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I am a spring new bee, 
trying to import gs-rest-service-complete into my STS , I am able to import but getting compilation error in pom.xml

> Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE from/to spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release):
>   Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM  "

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Can anyone guide what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Do you get the same if you run `mvn clean install` from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy is the problem.
You need to ensure the proxies section in either the global settings settings.xml  under  ([maven install]/conf/) or user settings (${user.home}/.m2 ) is configured correctly

```xml
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```